# Start a new Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

Using Android Studio, I have my MainActiviy class with a Placeholder fragment.  This fragment has buttons, but one has to load an Activity.  How does one do this?  I was told to try something like the below, but the new Intent does not work.

```
Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.class, AnotherActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
 });
```

Comment: Please post your current attempt/code. This is a broad question that should be able to be answered by reading the android official documentation. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) you can see that to start an activity you'll want to use the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Currently you're using `MainActivity.class` in a place that requires a context object. If you're currently in an activity, just passing `this` is enough. A fragment can get the activity via the `getActivity()` function.

Your full code above should look like this

```
Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I'm inside a PlaceHolder fragment inside MainActivity?  Is it possible to do it in there?  I've tried so many things with no luck.

Comment: In that case, replace `this` with `getActivity()`

Comment: My app crashes after following the above stated steps

Comment: Hi, how can I start an activity from an independent fragment? I mean when it does not have any activity parent.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `getActivity()` to launch an `Activity` from `Fragment`.

**From a Fragment:** `Context` is parent activity `(getActivity())`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi, how can I start an activity from an independent fragment? I mean when it does not have any activity parent.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to use it inside **onBindViewHolder**, you may do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_ID);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent(getActivity(), CallingActivity.class);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of fragment, write getActivity() to get activity context instead of giving the name of activity explicitly.
For example, if you want to open SecondActivity from a fragment,

Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.xml);
StartActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

If it is in holder:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
       val intent = Intent(context, AnotherActivity::class.java)
       intent.putExtra("text", "From fragment") . // send data
       context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

And in the `AnotherActivity`:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_another.*


class AnotherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another)
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        textView.text = "Received text:" + intent.getStringExtra("text")!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fragment you have to use getactivity().... For Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```