# Go with fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android

I have problem with communication with fragment with my activity. I don't have idea how communication this

```
public class MyDreamsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_addream:
                // go to Add DreamActvity.class
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: put your activity code and  all your fragment code as well

Comment: I have start with Fragmnt to Activty

Comment: do your want to start an activity from your fragment or you want to go back from fragment to previous activity ?

Comment: I want to start an activity from my fragment

Comment: If you have started your application, you already have activity started. Plese describe in more detail, what do you want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You have to call the activity of the fragment with `getActivity()`

There is already an [old question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619113/start-a-new-activity-from-fragment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DreamActvity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);