# I cannot setonClickListener RelativeLayout on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a relative layout inside a fragment. The fragment is inside MainActivity. I want to make `setonClickListener` event on it to open a new activity. I want to make the relative layout `rlLogOut` to open `SignInActivity` activity. But how do I put the `setOnClickListener` event on the fragment. Is it on the OtherFragment.kt or in the MainActivity

I've tried to make the `setOnClickListener` inside the MainActivity, and I know thats not the solution. I think the intent is the problem. But I don't know the syntax for it. I'm new in kotlin.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_others.*


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 *
 */
class OtherFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rlLogOut.setOnClickListener{
        val mainIntent = Intent(
            this@OtherFrament,
            SignInActivity::class.java
        )
        startActivity(mainIntent)
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_others, container, false)
}
}
```

I expect that when the `rlLogOut` clicked, `SignInActivity` activity is opened. Thanks for helping.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619113/start-a-new-activity-from-fragment/28619264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater, 
      container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_others, container, false)


  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) 
      rlLogOut.setOnClickListener {
            val mainIntent = Intent(requireActivity(),  SignInActivity::class.java)
            requireActivity().startActivity(mainIntent)
      }    
  }
```