# How to open an activity from fragment in Android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to open new activity from fragment but getting error please tell me the right way to do it.

Comment: `getting error please tell me the right way to do it.` show code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start a new Activity from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619113/start-a-new-activity-from-fragment)

Comment: why you don't try find answer by yourself before asking?

Answer (score 0):

try this `getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));`

Comment: `getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class));` ??

Comment: this is code to start activity from fragment

Comment: I am not down voter. why `this`?

Comment: `new Intent(this` why `this`?

Comment: it is context paramter, you can use `getActivity()` instead, or `getContext()`